# Setter and getter not working

Tags: java, string, setter, getter

This is my assignment about setter and getter and it is not working for some reason.
Could anyone check what the problem is for me?
Thank you.

```
public class FlightTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

        String name;
        String number;
        String Orig;
        String Desti;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        Flight data = new Flight ();

        System.out.print ("Airline Name: ");
        String AirlineName = scan.nextLine ();
        data.setAirlineName (name);

        System.out.print ("Flight Number: ");
        String FlightNumber = scan.nextLine ();
        data.setFlightNumber (number);

        System.out.print ("Origin: ");
        String Origin = scan.nextLine();
        data.setOrigin (Orig);

        System.out.print ("Destination: ");
        String Destination = scan.nextLine ();
        data.setDestination (Desti);

        System.out.println (data);
    }   
}





public class Flight

{

    private String AirlineName;

    private String FlightNumber;

    private String Origin;

    private String Destination;

    public String setAirlineName()
    {
        String Name = AirlineName;
        return Name;
    }

    public Flight ()
    {
        AirlineName = "";
        FlightNumber = "";
        Origin = "";
        Destination = "";
    }

    public String getAirlineName()
    {
        return AirlineName;
    }

    public void setAirlineName (String name)
    {
        AirlineName = name;
    }

    public String getFlightNumber ()
    {
        return FlightNumber;
    }

    public void setFlightNumber (String number)
    {
        FlightNumber = number;
    }

    public String getOrigin ()
    {
        return Origin;
    }

    public void setOrigin (String Orig)
    {
        Origin = Orig;
    }

    public String getDestination ()
    {
        return Destination;
    }

    public void setDestination (String Desti)
    {
        Destination = Desti;
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
        String result = AirlineName + " flight number " + FlightNumber + " leaves from " + Origin + " to " + Destination + ".";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "not working" in more detail :) It has endless different meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're reading the Scanner newLine() calls into new variables, and then passing in variables that haven't been initialized. For example, I think you want something like this:

```
System.out.print ("Airline Name: ");
name = scan.nextLine ();
data.setAirlineName (name);
```

Note that the second line reads the nextLine() into the variable that you're passing into the setter.

Comment: Note that it's this way for all of individual sections.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the problem:

```
    String AirlineName = scan.nextLine ();
    data.setAirlineName (name);
```

You are reading a name and putting it into `AirlineName`, then calling the setter with a **different** variable as its argument.

In fact, you should get a compilation error telling you that `name` is not initialized.

You also have a second (bogus) setAirlineName method as follows:

```
public String setAirlineName()
{
    String Name = AirlineName;
    return Name;
}
```

... which is not a proper setter.  But it looks like your `main` method doesn't call it, so that's not the cause of your problems.  (You are calling the `setAttributeName(String)` overload ...)

Finally, please, please, PLEASE, learn to follow standard Java style conventions for identitiers.  A variable or attribute name should **not** start with an uppercase letter.  Change your `AirlineName` attributes and variables to `airlineName`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You have this method:

```
public String setAirlineName()
{
    String Name = AirlineName;
    return Name;
}
```

Which conflicts with your actual setter because they are the same name but of different return types, and hence the compiler might be spitting errors, which I assume is what you mean by "not working":

```
public void setAirlineName (String name)
{
    AirlineName = name;
}
```

`String setAirlineName(void)` was probably meant to be `String getAirlineName(void)`, which you have already implemented just as a basic getter is intended to be:

```
public String getAirlineName()
{
    return AirlineName;
}
```

As [Dante617 has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939348/setter-and-getter-not-working/3939377#3939377), another mistake is that you're using different local variables to read input and ignoring the ones you declared (and didn't initialize) before your `Scanner` object.

Comment: This is my second [homework] answer, however I think it's perfectly fine to be more direct but compensate by offering an explanation of what's happening, since conflicting method signatures can be challenging to track down.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the variable `AirlineName` but passing a different **uninitialized** variable `name` to the setter:

```
String AirlineName = scan.nextLine ();
data.setAirlineName (name);
                     ^^^^
```

Same is the case with other 3 variables `FlightNumber`, `Origin` and `Destination`.